# Favicon.ico and static servers?

Tags: html, http, request, favicon

Static servers are (partial) for not sending the main site cookies for every request.

Also they help with splitting connection( subdomains) so that the browser will be able to download in parallel.

But I looked at viewsource of the  http://winterba.sh/copacabana

And in the `head` section they used the same facivon name but via specific location

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/favicon.ico">
```

Why did they do that ? what benefit does it provides ?

[This is suppose to be when I want to load the favicon but  with a different name](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=fCK3MMV8iYcC&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=%22You%20can%20specify%20an%20alternate%20name%20for%20the%20icon%20file%20with%20a%22&source=bl&ots=F5E03mDiui&sig=yq835iEKw-tKu-axovQ8zJj_BHQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GxXXUJLvGoPL0QX7kYHoAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22You%20can%20specify%20an%20alternate%20name%20for%20the%20icon%20file%20with%20a%22&f=false) .

But why should i do it ? the browser searches `favicon.ico` automatically. ( and they didnt rename it)

Once the favicon is downloaded , the next time it will be taken from the cache...

so ...why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a CDN. The whole purpose of a CDN is to serve static files fast. The file is probably called favicon.ico because that's what favicons are usually called, and is not relevant.

Comment: They could have remove the entire line (and save 90 bytes))and the webserver would have downloaded the file automatically. the only difference is that it _might_ send an existing cookie for the **first** request of the favicon.  no ?

Comment: Except it would only try to download the file from the same server as the main site, which is not the CDN. So the line *has* to be there in order to tell the browser that the favicon is in the CDN server.

Comment: if cookie length is less than 90 bytes - it is a lousy decision ( using cdn fo favicon) , otherwise - it is ok.

Comment: It's not purely a cookie issue. The biggest problem that a CDN can solve is download speed.